# Passing and receiving arrays in PhP

Tags: php, arrays, get

I am trying to pass an array by using

```
$variables=questions_file='.($questions_file).'&amp;questions_id='.($questions_id).'&amp;count_hindi='.$count_hindi;
echo '<Redirect method="GET">startCall.php?'.$variables.'</Redirect>';
```

questions_file and questions_id are both arrays

```
foreach($question_records as $record=>$question)
                {
                    $questions_file[$i]=$question['file_name'].'_'.$question['concept_tested'];
                    $questions_id[$i]=$question['question_id'];
                    echo $questions_file[$i]. "\n";
                    $i++;
                }
```

So when I echo the array, it shows perfectly. But when I pass it on to another file using the code above, and I try printing the array elements it prints blank. I tried using serialize and unserialize, but it still does not work

I want to now retrieve the values by using

```
$questions_id=(array)($_REQUEST['questions_id']);
$questions_file=(array)($_REQUEST['questions_file']);
```

But when I try to access the members.

Upon using:

```
$questions_file= urldecode(http_build_query($questions_file));
            $questions_url= urldecode(http_build_query($questions_id));
            $url = $server.'/startCall.php?call_id='.$call_id.'&phone='.$phone.'&questions_id='.$questions_id.'&questions_file='.$questions_file.'&student_id='.$student_id.'&story='
            .$story.'&call_number='.$call_number.'&question_number=0&response=0&count_english=0&count_hindi=0';
```

I get

```
questions_file 0=q1_vocab&1=q3_comp&2=q5_crit&3=q7_gra
```

I want to get

```
questions_file[0]=q1_vocab&questions_file[1]=q3_comp&questions_file[2]=q5_crit&questions_file[3]=q7_gra
```

Comment: can you elaborate on 'not working'...?

Comment: wondering if it would help to escape your $variables string so that the ampersand is properly transmitted, as well...

Comment: @RobP how do i escape the variables and please check my updated response

Answer (score 1):

When you echo arrays, you just get the word 'Array'. So what you're likely to get is:

```
echo 'myArr=' . $myArr;
// myArr=Array
```

When you need to pass arrays in GET, you need to explicitly define them. For example:

```
myArr[assoc]=1&myArr[assoc2]=2&myArr2[0]=1&myArr2[1]=2&myOtherArr[]=1
```

Will give you:

```
$_GET['myArr'] -> ('assoc' => 1, 'assoc2' => 2)
$_GET['myArr2'] -> (0 => 1, 1 => 2)
$_GET['myOtherArr'] -> (0 -> 1)
```

Luckily, PHP has a [built in function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for you:

```
$myArr = array('assoc' => 1, 'assoc2' => 2);
$get = array(
    'myArr' => $myArr,
    'myOtherArr' => array(1, 2)
);
echo urldecode(http_build_query($myArr));
// myArr[assoc]=1&myArr[assoc2]=2&myOtherArr[0]=1&myOtherArr[1]=2
```

Comment: what if my program dynamically initializes the array and so I don't know how many variables there are. I can always create the parameter string using a for loop but are there less manual ways?

Comment: Look at the updated answer. You can pass your array even if it's dynamic, to that function. But I wouldn't suggest that, because you'd be passing a lot of data via GET. Have you thought about using a form and submitting it via POST?

Comment: thank you very much..will accept the answer once I've changed my code and tested. Really helps!!

Comment: I am getting questions_file0=q1_vocab&1=q3_comp&2=q5_crit and not questions_file[0]=q1_vocab&questions_file[1]=q3_comp&questions_file[2]=q5_cri. can u tell me why?

Comment: Can you show me your code? You need to put the array you want to export into a parent array, with the key as the name of the array. Look at my examples above

Comment: You're not containing them in an associative array with the proper key. It should be: `$questions_id=array('questions_id' => $_REQUEST['questions_id']);
$questions_file=array('questions_file' =>$_REQUEST['questions_file']);` Also there's no need to cast an array into an array

Comment: how can i retrieve the array elements after using the lines above..when i do echo questions_file i get Array and when i do echo questions_file[0], I get blank as output

Comment: thanks for your older response. how can i retrieve the array elements after using the lines above..when i echo questions_file i get 'Array' and when i do echo questions_file[0], I get blank as output...this happens even though both are clearly arrays. Is there any other way to access their elements besides variable[0]? Or is there a problem with the array itself?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Use `var_dump($var)` to see exactly what goes on in variables. After the code I commented here you can use `http_build_query(array($questions_id, $questions_file))` to get your final query